# Remove an overlay image only after the original image has updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, attr

When creating a simple photo gallery with a crossfade effect I’m encountering weird behavior.

This is how it’s supposed to work: (1.) I fade in an overlay image on top of the original image, (2.) I change the src attribute of the underlying original image to that of the overlay image and, as a last step, (3.) I remove the overlay image.

```
$("#photo").attr({
    src: imageURL,
    alt: altText
});
$("#overlay-photo").remove();
```

The above code (showing the last two steps) works when all images are cached. It briefly flashes the old, unchanged image before displaying the updated image when the cache is empty, presumably because the change of attributes and the removal of the src attribute happens at the same time and remove might be a tad quicker than changing the src attribute and updating the image.

```
$("#photo").attr({
    src: imageURL,
    alt: altText
}).each(function () {
    $("#overlay-photo").remove();
});
```

As you can see, I tried to somehow attach a callback function (in this case with each) but that didn’t solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ckeck this out. I think it will work for you:

```
   $('#overlay-photo').fadeIn(500,function() {

        $('#photo').hide().one('load',function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
            $('#overlay-photo').remove();
        }).attr({
            src: imageURL,
            alt: altText
        });
    });
```

Comment: @Michael Kaltenecker If you have some problem please comment and I'll try to solve.You may need to adjust the css properties.

Comment: Yeah, I think the CSS properties are now the problem. I was using a negative margin on the overlay photo to put it directly above the original photo. Since this original photo is now no more shown for a split second the whole page jumps up for that split second.

Comment: Ah! I just removed `.hide()` and `$(this).fadeIn()`. It seems to work without it and the flashing is gone. Since the original photo is no more hidden, the negative margin is also not a problem. Is it necessary to hide the original photo or can I just leave that out?

Comment: @Michael Kaltenecker if your `#overlay-photo` covers the original image. then `.hide()` and `$(this).fadeIn()` not necessary.